# getting value from a NSBlockOperation?

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

hi guys im very frustrated because i want to improve a code but i'm not getting good results this is my piece of code

```
NSBlockOperation *blockOperation1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
        value1 = [self getDiferences:0.0 finx:width iniy:0.0 finy:cuartoheith image:imagen1 imagetoComapare:imagen2];
    }];
    [queue addOperation:blockOperation1];

NSBlockOperation *blockOperation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
        value2 = [self getDiferences:0.0 finx:width iniy:0.0 finy:cuartoheith image:imagen1 imagetoComapare:imagen2];
    }];
    [queue addOperation:blockOperation2];

NSBlockOperation *blockOperation3 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
        value3 = [self getDiferences:0.0 finx:width iniy:0.0 finy:cuartoheith image:imagen1 imagetoComapare:imagen2];
    }];
    [queue addOperation:blockOperation3];

NSBlockOperation *blockOperation4 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
        value4 = [self getDiferences:0.0 finx:width iniy:0.0 finy:cuartoheith image:imagen1 imagetoComapare:imagen2];
    }];
    [queue addOperation:blockOperation4];
```

i want use this values outside the NSBlockOperation like this valuetotal=value1+value2+value3+value4; please help or help with a better solution

Comment: I hope your are declaring your `value` variables with `__block` modifier? So why don't you use GCD and `dispatch_group` to perform your operations?

Comment: yep im declaring __block float value before the block but is empty

Answer (score 3):

Add another operation which is dependent on your other operations (using `addDependency:`), and add your code there. Queue this operation. It will wait for all others to finish, and then use their output.

For example,

```
NSBlockOperation *blockOperationFinal = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
    valueTotal = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4;
}];

[blockOperationFinal addDependency:blockOperation1];
[blockOperationFinal addDependency:blockOperation2];
[blockOperationFinal addDependency:blockOperation3];
[blockOperationFinal addDependency:blockOperation4];

[queue addOperation:blockOperationFinal];
```

Comment: im kind a newbie so im not getting what are you trying to say me, it will be helpful a piece of code if is not so much bother XD

Comment: thanks for example code but my problem stills, because i need the value total outside all blocks for a compare XD

Comment: You have to move the compare inside the new block operation, or synchronize in another way. This is the easiest I find here. you can also use `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` on the queue itself, but this will block your calling thread - if it's the main thread, this will block the GUI. Better have it inside the final operation.

Answer (score 0):

one block operation is enough, cause it is able to add more blocks, and execute concurrently, meanwhile provide a block to trigger when all blocks are completed, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [array addObject:@"op1"];
}];
[operation addExecutionBlock:^{
    [array addObject:@"op2"];
}];

[[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] addOperation:operation];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"array:%@", array);
}];
```